# What is the best way to make a graph in WPF? (or in general that would apply to WPF as well)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So I am making a piece of software in WPF, and I want to be able to make graphs out of the data I am storing.  Just line graphs with x and y axises.  Ideally I would want them to have a nice elegant simplicity to them.

I know WPF doesn't come with graphs, and I have tried ZedGraph in a WinForms project, but I thought frankly it looked ugly.

What is the best way to make simple, elegant graphs in WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WPF Toolkit is available. It is free from CodePlex. It contains some nice charting classes.

It can be downloaded [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117). 
There is some commentary [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Try [VisiFire](http://www.VisiFire.com). It looks good. It works well.

[image]

Comment: Is it working yet with WPF?  Or still only Silverlight.  It looks nice!

Comment: I've used it with WPF without any issues. When you download the library, there are several WPF projects included as samples.

Comment: Visifire supports Data binding. Checkout the full feature list here: http://visifire.com/visifire_features.php

Answer (score 5):

You can get the Silverlight Chart Controls [running on WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/11/18/silverlight-chart-control-running-in-wpf.aspx), they're quite nice (and free).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft purchased some of the IP from Dundas and supplied their winforms/asp.net charts as [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

Since they will render as images they should be integrate without too much effort.

I have used the underlying dundas functionality and like it so would assume that these are respectable free controls.

Comment: Aren't these WinForms charts?  The question asks for WPF charts.  Am I missing something?

Comment: They render to a bitmap (in memory if desired), as such they can then be placed into any widget set that can display such things (all of them these days). The integration isn't so easy (an supporting interaction would be problematic) but most don't and are simple canvases...